# What makes a condition unary vs. n-ary (n>1)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

For any two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, a set $W$ is a connection of $A$ with $B$ if

1. $Z\in W\implies (\exists x\in A)(\exists y\in B)[Z=\{x,y\}]$
2. $(\forall x\in A)(\exists !y\in B)[\{x,y\}\in W]$
3. $(\forall y\in B)(\exists !x\in A)[\{x,y\}\in W]$

I know that each of the conditions 1-3 are definite conditions (and indeed being a connection in general is a definite condition). But I'm having trouble telling when I should consider something an $n$-ary condition $(n>1)$ vs a unary condition.

I want to use the Axiom of Separation (Zermelo axioms) which requires a definite condition to be unary. The condition that I want to use is that of a set being a connection. But, to me, that would be a ternary condition, say $P(A,B,W)$. So I would have to "decompose" this ternary condition into unary conditions and apply the separation axiom multiple times, no?

Answer (score 1):

Axiom schema of Separation, in its more general form says that :

> If $\phi(x)$ is a formula (in which $z$ does not occur free) then $$( \forall w_1 ... w_n ) ( \forall y ) ( \exists z ) ( \forall x ) ( x \in z \leftrightarrow ( x \in y \wedge \phi (x, w_1, ... w_n) ) )$$

or, in words, given any set $y$, there is a set $z$ such that, given any set $x$, $x$ is a member of $z$ if and only if $x$ is a member of $y$ and $\phi$ holds for $x$, where $w_1, ... w_n (n \ge 0 )$ are the *parameters*.

So, using the formula $P(A,B,W)$, you have a formula with $W$ free and $A$ and $B$ as *parameters*. Then you can use it in the Axiom schema, obtaining that :

> $( \forall w_1 ) ( \forall w_2 ) ( \forall y ) ( \exists z ) ( \forall x ) ( x \in z \leftrightarrow ( x \in y \wedge P(w_1, w_2, x) ) )$.

Answer (score 0):

Say, $P(A,B,W)$ is the first order proposition that expresses that $W$ is a connection between $A$ and $B$, Then consider
$${\rm isConn}(W):= " \exists A\exists B:P(A,B,W)"\,.$$

Comment: Right, but then what's the point in distinguishing between unary and n-ary (n>1) if we can just make an (n>1)-ary condition a unary condition by doing what you did?

Comment: @5space, suppose instead of trying to axiomatize sets, we were trying to axiomatize group theory. Then even if $x$ and $y$ are elements of a group, nonetheless $(x,y)$ may not be. So unary conditions and binary conditions are, in general, very different; you cannot just make a binary condition unary in group theory. Its only very strong "foundational" theories like ZFC or PA that have ways to "internalize" the notion of an ordered pair, that provide a way to turn $n$-ary operations into unary operations.

Comment: @user18921: That is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @5space, you're welcome!